# How can I connect usb keyboard to Pro Mini atmega328 Board 5V 16M

Tags: keyboard, arduino, atmega, hardware

As a new person to arduino I have several basic questions . I reaLly appreciate any answer or help you guys offer me

1. is it possible to connect keyboard(HID) with pro mini with out using usb host Shield
2. any method or ways that I can connect keyboard with the Pro Mini atmega328 Board
3. after connect how to read keyboard inputs

**Pro Mini atmega328 Board** Which I'm going to program.

www.aliexpress.com/item/1pcs-Pro-Mini-atmega328-Board-5V-16M-Arduino-Compatible-Nano/32249042953.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know any library capable of interfacing to USB peripherals without any shield. That's because USB is really complicated.

You can do it yourself, checking the V-USB and making a sort of inversion, but I don't know whether it is possible.

A possible "solution" is to use a PS2 keyboard. PS2 is a far easier protocol, so it's easier to understand for a small uC.

For instance you can look [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PS2Keyboard) for a library which can read from a PS2 keyboard. Otherwise search for that protocol and implement a reader.

Comment: any other help i really need to read usb input with out using shield

Comment: I'd really like to build a spaceship using just an arduino and aluminum foil, but it's technically impossible. Now, if you don't want a shieldless arduino for it, go for Arduino Mega2560 ADK (which has one integrated). If the problem is that the shield is too big, [here](https://www.circuitsathome.com/arduino_usb_host_shield_projects) they speak about a mini version; you will be able to find it also on ebay if you search for "arduino usb host mini". If you don't want external hardware.. I think it is impossible, but try to invert the V-USB library